# Cast object of type Any to an implementation of class + interface

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to cast an object like following:

```
fun <A> test(obj: X) where A: Class1, A: Interface1 {
}

fun testFunction(obj: Any) {
     if (obj is Class1 && obj is Interface1) {
         // how to do this now??? smart casting is not working
         test(obj) // not working, compiler error
     }
}
```

Can I somehow convert the `obj` instance to an instance of an oject that is `Class1` and extends `Interface1` in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to provide a specific type to match `A`, you will not be able to do it in a way that satisfies the compiler.

However what you can do is use a private function combined with type assertions to create a facade that is type-safe on the outside:

```
private fun test_unsafe(obj: Any) {
    obj as Class1
    obj as Interface1

    //obj is now of type <Class1 & Interface1>
}

fun <A> test(obj: A) where A: Class1, A: Interface1 = test_unsafe(obj)

fun testFunction(obj: Any) {
     if (obj is Class1 && obj is Interface1) {
         test_unsafe(obj)
     }
}
```

Ensuring that `test_unsafe` is only called with the correct type will not be enforced by the compiler and will be your responsibility. But outside callers will get a type-safe interface to use with this solution.

Comment: Great, thanks. I need this to cast the `Activity` I get from the android framework to an implementation that also implements a preknown interface - I make sure that this is always true. Thanks a lot for this solution

Comment: In that case you could also consider `test(cls: Class1, intf: Interface1)`, allowing access to the required methods without requiring type magic.

Comment: that's true and thanks for the suggestion, in my case it's a library that I use a lot already and it that does already make the assumption that the object is an activity and implements the correct interface.